# Why does leiningen download 1GB (almost) of jar indexes and how to stop that?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Leiningen downloaded nearly 1GB of jar index information from repo1.maven.org and clojars.org. Why does it need to download that huge amount of information? And is there any way to prevent that?

The directory in question is: `~/.lein/indeces`

It contains the following folders:

```
https___clojars.org_repo_
https___repo1.maven.org_maven2_
```

The maven.org folder contains 849MB!

Here is my project definition:

```
(defproject test-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :main test-project.core
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [camel-snake-kebab "0.3.1" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]])
```

Thanks

Comment: How many depenendencies do you *have* in your project?

Comment: Reproduction steps? What project.clj and user profile are in place here? If you can't tell us how to reproduce the issue...

Comment: (By "jar indexes", do you mean to assert 1GB of content *other than actual jars*? This is quite unheard of, and as such almost certainly specific to your dependency chain).

Comment: Updated question to be more specific.

Comment: Ahh. Those are generated by `lein search` -- a plugin not installed by default. I'd suggest perhaps uninstalling it? :)

Comment: I would like to prevent that from happening entirely. Is that possible? Seems like such a waste to download all of that data.

Comment: Care to post your `~/.lein/profiles.clj`?

Comment: If you didn't intentionally install that plugin, by the way, it might be interesting to figure out just which tool you use _did_. Perhaps you're using an IDE plugin for Clojure?

Comment: I don't have a `~/.lein/profiles.clj`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This content is maintained not by Leiningen itself, but [the `lein-search` plugin](https://github.com/Licenser/lein-search). I'd suggest uninstalling it (the plugin, that is) unless you consider its benefits worth the cost in time and storage.

To do so, remove references to `lein-search/lein-search` or `org.clojars.wuschel/lein-search` from your `~/.lein/profiles.clj` -- or, if this content was created while working in a different project, from the `project.clj` of that project.